# SHACL union shapes

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, shacl

I have framed a SPARQL query for the following use-case: If IfcWallStandardCase have a property 'FireRating', then the doors associated with it should have a property 'FireRating' as well.

The Data Graph

```
@prefix inst1: <https://someHost.com/PROJ1001#> .
@prefix :      <http://test.com/#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix ifcowl: <https://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifcOWL/IFC4_ADD1#> .
@prefix s4bldg: <https://saref.etsi.org/saref4bldg/> .
@prefix bot:   <https://w3id.org/bot#> .

inst1:Wall1  a  ifcowl:IfcWallStandardCase ;
    s4bldg:FireRating "2" ;
    bot:containsSubElement  inst1:Door1, inst1:Door2.
inst1:Door1 a ifcowl:IfcDoor ;
    s4bldg:FireRating  "2" .
inst1:Door2 a ifcowl:IfcDoor .
```

SPARQL Query

```
SELECT ?door
WHERE {{
   ?wall rdf:type ifcowl:IfcWallStandardCase.
   ?wall bot:containsElement ?val.
   ?wall s4bldg:FireRating ?val.
   }UNION{
   ?door rdf:type ifcowl:IfcDoor.
   ?door s4bldg:FireRating ?val.
   }}
```

I want to frame a SHACL shape for the same. From the SHACL advanced features, the closest option is to use the sh:union. Below, is my shape.

```
bot:BuildingShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ifcowl:IfcWallStandardCase;
    sh:rule [
        sh:subject sh:this;
        sh:predicate s4bldg:FireRating;
        sh:object ifcowl:IfcWallStandardCase;
        sh:union(
            [sh:path ifcowl:IfcDoor]
            [sh:path s4bldg:FireRating]
        )
    ].
```

But, it does not give me the result given by the SPARQL query. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the SPARQL query looks strange, is this correct? Why `?wall bot:containsElement ?val.
   ?wall s4bldg:FireRating ?val.` - which would only work if the element and the fire rating are the same given that `?val` is shared. Does this fit the data model?

Comment: also,can you say what exactly does not work? Also, did you miss the `a sh:TripleRule ;` part? And shouldn't the union be put into a [condition](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-af/#condition)?

Comment: If you can fetch the values that you would like to infer with a SPARQL query, why not simply convert that query into a SPARQL CONSTRUCT and use a SPARQL-based sh:rule?

Comment: Also, the sh:union is disconnected to anything. Either you want to use it as value of, say, sh:object or as sh:condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me that you need a sh:rule for this.  Try the following:

```
bot:BuildingShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ifcowl:IfcWallStandardCase;
    sh:property [
       sh:path bot:containsSubElement;
       sh:class ifcowl:IfcDoor ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path s4bldg:FireRating;
        sh:hasValue "2" ;
    ]
.
```

It may not be a full value, and you may want to use sh:in to specify the range of values for FireRating, but it may be worth thinking of it this way and maybe you can tweak to meet your specification.